# Make search view available in a generic way regarding AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, search, android-activity, android-manifest

I have followed the guide [Creating a Searchable Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity) to set up my search action. This works as expected. Now I have moved most of the code into an abstract base activity class. This way I want to make the search view available on more or less every activity.

The only problem is that I still need to add

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
```

into every activity element in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Is there a way to handle this generically as well?

Comment: One activity, and content in fragments?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess if you create a Searchable Activity, declare it with `searchable` metadata, and extend this Activity in another required activities. Will it work?

Comment: @KanakSony yeah, maybe, but the base activity should stay abstract and I cannot declare an unconcrete activity in the AndroidManifest.